# Allowed numer of roles per account and it's impact on Lambda functions extensively

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS has a limit of 1000 roles per account, and when we want to have fine grained access control to AWS resources accessed by the lambda we will end up creating a role per function and in a large scale deployment this might be a problem depending upon the granularity of the lambda function.

I guess this is a well-known issue within AWS Lambda community what is the solution for a fine-grained access control for architecture that favors smaller single-purpose lambda functions

Answer (score 3):

That's just the default account limit. You can request that Amazon raise the limit on your account.